# $http request success with error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I have the following simple code:

```
$http(request)
    .success(function(data){                                            
                ...
            })
    .error(function(data){
                ...
            });
```

One issue I get is when the response has caused an error, I get back an error in the JSON response, which I can see via data.error, however the way I have it working at the moment data.error is actually successful, rather than an error.

What would be the best way to handle this? Would it simple as an:

```
if (data.error){ ....
```

Comment: I didn't understand your intention. Do you want the error to trigger but it triggers on success?

Comment: You might be able to test for a specific string or substring within the response to further determine if it's an error or not.

Comment: yeah the error only triggers for example if data does not come back (which is correct) but on certain requests an error is caused and it is identifiable via data.error, however not sure what's the best way to control this within the response.

Comment: So I take it that on the server side you return a 200 response and return an error object, right?

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http):

> A response status code between 200 and 299 is considered a success
>   status and will result in the success callback being called. Note that
>   if the response is a redirect, XMLHttpRequest will transparently
>   follow it, meaning that the error callback will not be called for such
>   responses.

So if you're returning `data.error` in your JSON, but the response is being returned with a HTTP status code of 200, your `.error` handler will not get called.

To answer your question then, yes - doing something like `if (data.error) {... }` should do the trick.

Comment: exactly - I do actually get 200 back, as the response does come back, simply not in the correct format, as per the additional .error in the response.

Comment: Take note of @Sebastian Pederiva's answer though: .success and .error have been deprecated since Angular 1.4.4 in favour of using .then

Answer (score 1):

first at all you should not use .success and .error (see https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)

so you should use in the following way:

```
$http({
  method: 'GET',
  url: '/someUrl'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }, function errorCallback(response) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

hope this will help you!

Comment: That still doesn't answer his question though.